# Call to undefined method Imagick::getImageCompression()

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick

I'm having an issue using the [`getImageCompression()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagecompression.php) method from [`Imagick`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php%3a). When I use it I receive an error (haven't found any problem with any of the other methods so far):

```
$img = new imagick('/path/to/jpeg');
$img->getImageCompose(); // some value
$img->getImageCompression(); // Call to undefined method Imagick::getImageCompression()
$img->getImageCompressionQuality(); // some value
```

I'm running `PHP 5.3.10` with `php5-imagick 3.1.0` (I know [it's in beta](http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick), but [`getImageCompression()` was released in 2.2.2](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagecompression.php)) and `ImageMagick 6.6.9-7`.

Am I missing something or is the `getImageCompression()` method effectively missing (if so, is there an alternative for retrieving the image compression)?

Comment: +1 Nice question. Nicely formatted. Well explained. And you did your research. I wish every question was as good as yours!

Comment: Have you restarted your webserver? Some distributions do not restart the webserver after installing php-* packages so you need to do this manually to reload php files and new php modules.

Comment: I'm using `PHP cli` and AFAIK there is nothing to restart (sorry for not mentioning that in question). `php -r "print_r(phpinfo());" | grep imagick` gives me `imagick module` enabled with version `3.1.0RC1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find this method, neither in [2.2.2](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/imagick/tags/RELEASE_2_2_2/imagick_class.c?view=markup) nor in [3.1.0RC2](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/imagick/tags/imagick-3.1.0RC2/imagick_class.c?view=markup)

Setters are present (`setImageCompression()`) ; other getters you quoted are present too.

Seems like the manual is lying.

Comment: That's what I thought. There doesn't seem to be any open bugs about it either: https://bugs.php.net/search.php?search_for=imagick&boolean=0&limit=30&order_by=&direction=DESC&cmd=display&status=Open&bug_type=All&project=All&php_os=&phpver=&cve_id=&assign=&author_email=&bug_age=0&bug_updated=0, opening one then, will accept your answer as soon as bug is confirmed...

Comment: doesn't seem to be much activity with the bug, so accepting your answer before I forget about it.

Comment: @user359650 thanks, I hope for all of us they'll answer soon.